# Spring Security with Java EE Restful Service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, java-ee-6, spring-security-oauth2

I have created a Java EE 6 restfull service and tried to integrate that with Spring Security. But, all the time I get different weird exceptions. Which doesn't make any sense or may be make sense but at least not for me.

Direction structure of my application is something like this:

```
com.security
    UserDetailsSecurityConfig.java
com.service
    ApplicationConfig.java
    UserFacadeREST.java
com.config
    AppConfig.java
```

My entities are auto generated so no error seems to be there. But, yes the three files seems fishy to me as UserFacadeREST is working fine when I don't integrate my application with Spring Security.

> com.UserDetailsSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class UserDetailsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService( userDetailsService() );
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http
           .httpBasic().and()
           .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS ).and()
           .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole( "USER" );
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername( final String username ) 
                    throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                if( username.equals( "admin" ) ) {
                    return new User( username, "password", true, true, true, true,
                            Arrays.asList(
                            new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER" ),
                            new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN" )
                        )
                    );
                } else if ( username.equals( "user" ) ) {
                    return new User( username, "password", true, true, true, true,
                        Arrays.asList(
                            new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "ROLE_USER" )
                        )
                    );
                } 

                return null;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

> com.service.ApplicationConfig.java

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(com.service.UserFacadeREST.class);
    }

}
```

> com.service.UserFacadeREST.java

```
@Stateless
@Path("user")
public class UserFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<UpUser> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public UserFacadeREST() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(User entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }
    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

}
```

> com.config.AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import( UserDetailsSecurityConfig.class )
public class AppConfig {    
    @Bean 
    public ApplicationConfig applicationConfig() {
        return new ApplicationConfig();
    }
        @Bean 
    public UserFacadeREST userRestService() {
        return new UserFacadeREST();
    }   


}
```

In whole code I have made few changes for hit and trial. And currently, I am getting an exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no
>   ContextLoaderListener registered?

Before that I was getting another exception which was

> WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used

I am not getting what I am doing wrong in integrating Spring Security with Java EE 6. I am new to Spring so may be I am doing a blunder which seems obvious to me.

My web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="rest-sec" version="3.0">

    <display-name>rest</display-name>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- rest -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.labs.entities</param-value> <!-- won't find anything -->
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Disables servlet container welcome file handling. Needed for compatibility 
        with Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat 7.0 -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file />
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

You need to tell the filter where to look for your context (it's default is to look in a place that is not used by the servlet you created). In your filter add an init param:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

> WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used

Do you have 2 beans of type `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? Or is your `UserDetailsSecurityConfig` being loaded twice?

Comment: I have done the change and still getting the same exception. I have also looked into the code and didn't find any multiple entries of WebSecurityCOnfigurerAdapter. But, after applying this change exception changed a little bit: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: initializer not registered?

Comment: Why do you need the `DispatcherServlet` anyway? Maybe you should just use a `ContextLoaderListener`? I think Jersey 2 tries to do that for you so maybe that's the problem (Jersey loaded the Spring context for you and then you load it again)?

Comment: P.S. I told you to put the init-param in the wrong place (it goes in the filter). See updated answer. But if you don't need the servlet then the advice changes.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply it has stopped giving me that exception but, now giving me an exception on my persistance unit. org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'PU' is defined. While PU is my persistance unit as you can seen in my UserFacadeREST

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer then and start a new thread about the entity manager.

Comment: I have accepted the answer and now created another thread though it's giving me similar exception but, at least after initialization .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783227/spring-security-with-java-ee-rest-throws-no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-cont